# Tensorflow image classification example

Tags: tensorflow

This is my first time doing image classification, I followed this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

I'm wondering, how do I take that model, and actually use it to make predictions?

I would just to put one image into the model, and would ideally like to get a prediction % of whether it thinks its a dog or a cat.

I saved the model using:

```
model.save(my_model.h5)
```

But am really lost at the next steps.

Comment: That will involve building API to expose your model + building some kind of user interface for user to interact and upload images. Here's an example you can try to follow to get more information: https://medium.com/@BhashkarKunal/image-classification-api-creation-using-tensorflow-flask-mongodb-61a53835e62d

Comment: Sorry Yilun, I've edited my question, dont need an UI to upload images, just happy to use code to point it to a particular image. I just want to know how to use it to make predictions on single or batch of images.

Comment: Use the [`predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) method?

Comment: @simonsays Your `model` object should have the `model.predict()` method which should be used to make predictions. For new images that you want to predict, let them go through the same process as the images you used to train your model, and the model will output the probabilities for each image for each class in your model.

Answer (score 0):

There's another Tensorflow tutorial which uses model.predict() specifically: [Basic classification: Classify images of clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)

Not sure if my code is correct all the way but I tried to extend the prediction part of the cats/dogs tutorial using model.predict_generator() though I can't seem to entirely understand the results I get. Adapted code from this second tutorial: [Tutorial on using Keras flow_from_directory and generators](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720)

```
# Preparing the testing dataset
test_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cat_dog_testing') # directory with test images
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # rescaling pixels 0 to 1
test_generator = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=6,
                                                  directory=test_dir,
                                                  shuffle=False,
                                                  target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH),
                                                  class_mode=None)
STEP_SIZE_TEST=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size
test_generator.reset()
pred=model_new.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I built a tensorflow image classification workflow so that you can both train and classify images with no code. It's on FlyteHub if you want to see it

https://flytehub.org/trainandclassifyimages

Happy to collaborate if you have improvements you want to make to the codebase :)

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192). If the tool or library is not free-to-use, please also mention this in your answer.